# Keyboard is out of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have ported the ICS keyboard and it works well. But I am facing a problem in LDPI/MDPI devices. the last row is cut off.

link to a picture 
http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/6343/screenshot1321903105942.png

The definition of the keyobard view is in the following XML.

InputView extends LinearLayout

```
<com.android.inputmethod.latin.InputView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:latin="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/inputmethod.latin.ported"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/key_preview_backing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/key_preview_backing_height" />

    <!-- On tablets, the suggestions strip is centered with horizontal paddings on both sides
         because width of the landscape mode is too long for the suggestions strip. This
         LinearLayout is required to hold the paddings. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/suggestions_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/suggestions_strip_padding"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/suggestions_strip_height"
            style="?attr/suggestionsStripBackgroundStyle" />
        <com.android.inputmethod.latin.SuggestionsView
            android:id="@+id/suggestions_view"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/suggestions_strip_height"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            style="?attr/suggestionsViewStyle" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/suggestions_strip_padding"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/suggestions_strip_height"
            style="?attr/suggestionsStripBackgroundStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.LatinKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.android.inputmethod.latin.InputView>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. To solve this I reduced

```
<dimen name="key_preview_backing_height">240dip</dimen>
```

from 240 to 200 and

```
<integer name="max_more_suggestions_row">6</integer>
```

from 6 to 5 which didn't affect the keyboard behavior but fixed the same problem. You can turn on the visual debug by setting sVISUALDEBUG in LatinImeLogger.java to true and see the area occupied by key_preview_backing in transparent red.

I have another issue when you cannot click on anything behind this view.